# What's the proper way to package dough?

Tags: baking

Say I wanted to make a large amount of dough, then divide it into smaller portions to send to cafes, etc. How would I package the divided dough? Do I just put it in a plastic bag or something similar?

Note sure if this matters: the dough will come from an overnight cold rise. Refrigerated shipping will be required.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap in freezer-safe cling wrap and then put that into freezer-safe ziplock bags. Use sharpie on the outer bags before bagging to write the date and what's in it (or put a sticker on it if this is more of a professional operation or if it's something the public will be buying directly). If this is something you'll be doing a lot you should get a vacuum sealer for the outer bag.

Comment: I won't be freezing the dough, but I guess freezer-safe cling wrap would still work. But the dough will be pretty large -- will be a pain to cling wrap it. The largest ziplock bags might struggle to contain the dough. Won't vacuum sealing dough crush it?

Comment: @CookingNewbie — I suggest the freezer-safe material not because you'll be freezing but because it's a better material that isn't air-permeable like standard cling wrap or zip-lock bags. For the vacuum sealer, no it won't crush the dough. The dough itself doesn't go into the sealer. The sealer just removes the air and then melts the plastic to seal. There is large cling wrap and large freezer bags (2 gallon can be purchased easily). How large are your portions of dough?

Comment: They will be 3-4 pound portions. Don't think the freezer bags at the grocery stores will be big enough. Is your suggestion the standard solution in the industry? Seems like a lot of plastic.